# Show all failed tests of multiple test suite in one testNG report

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, selenium, testng

Actually I'm testing multiple website for my company. All the website have the same structure and i'm testing various things on each.

For my test i have a Selenium Java Maven project using TestNG. For each web site, i've created a sub folder and generate a specific testing.xml file to specify each test i'm doing for the website.

Here the structure : https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTB8a.jpg

My testing.xml files are like this :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
  <suite name="Test suite website 1" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
    <test name="Test1">
      <classes>
        <class name="package.for.mytest1"></class>
      </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test2">
      <classes>
        <class name="package.for.mytest2"></class>
      </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test3">
      <classes>
        <class name="package.for.mytest3"></class>
      </classes>
    </test>
 </suite>
```

How can I merge this 4 test suite in one testNG report ? And if it's possible, is there a way to only show the unstable or failed test on it ?

Any ideas ? Thanks for your help

Comment: to define what to report using `testng`, you can make use of  `Reporter` class, documented here -http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/Reporter.html

Comment: Can I regroup multiple testing results like this ? How can I don it's a bit confuse for me ...

Answer (score 1):

Try [Allure](http://allure.qatools.ru/) it could easily generate combined report for several suites and show only failed/broken tests by default.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can Use Suite-XML tag in TestNG.xml file to report all your test in single report or implement a reporter of your own to collect all the results and then at the end flush everything into report of your own format with whatever information you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate testng.xml file in which you can give the path of other testsuites files.

eg:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >


<suite name= "Allsuites" verbose="1" preserve-order="true" >
    <listeners>
      <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter"/>
      <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter"/>
    </listeners>


    <suite-files preserve-order="true">
     <suite-file path="testng1.xml" /> 
     <suite-file path="testng2.xml" />
     <suite-file path="testng3.xml" />
    </suite-files>  


</suite>
```